# How to change result of Curl command in powershell

Tags: powershell, curl

Can you help me this issue?
How to change result of Curl command in powershell like this :

[image]

to success or failure

Answer (score 0):

You just use an if statement or a try catch statement and put in the message you want.

```
($UrlOrIPA = 'stackoverflow.com')

($UrlOrIPA = '10.0.119.61:8101')

try
{
    curl -Uri $UrlOrIPA -UseBasicParsing | Select Status*
    "Testing $UrlOrIPA"
    'Success'
}
catch 
{
    "Testing $UrlOrIPA"
    'Failure'
}




StatusCode StatusDescription
---------- -----------------
       200 OK               
Testing stackoverflow.com
Success


Testing 10.0.119.61:8101
Failure
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! You're very kind